# Checking occurrence of values within two vectors simultaneously

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

My goal is find how many times a complex number exists in the two vectors.

```
wr_den : vector with real part
wi_den : vector with imaginary part
ordem_den[0] : vectors number of elements (in this case is 3)
```

Example:

```
wr_den[0] = 1 wi_den[0] = 1
wr_den[1] = 1 wi_den[1] = 1
wr_den[2] = 1 wi_den[2] = 0
```

Result:

```
index 0: 2
index 1: 2
index 2: 1
```

My code

```
for (it = 0; it < ordem_den[0]; it++)
  {
    times  = 0;
    for(contador = 0; contador < ordem_den[0]; contador++)
     {   
      p = wr_den[it];
      x = wr_den[contador];

      y = wi_den[it];
      t = wi_den[contador];
      if ((p == x) && (t == y))
       {
        times++;
       }
     }
       }
```

Comment: Is your code working? If not, what's the problem?

Comment: No, it isnt. "times" does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **[std::multiset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)** would probably be the thing here, assuming that the perceived problem is O(n^2) time of current code.

Just first iterate throught the index positions, putting those numbers in the set. Then iterate again, now checking number of occurrences of each number at each given index position.

You don't specify the number types used. Be aware that non-integer floating point values may not compare as equal even though they look equal on output. That may or may not be a problem.

Comment: You said something interesting. Their type is double. I will look this "multiset".

Comment: Problem solved. I used setprecision(12) and verified that they are a little different. Thanks man.